# Align text of different size to the bottom

Tags: css, alignment

I have two divs with text of different sizes, that I want to align to the bottom.

They do successfully get aligned to the bottom of their parent, but they're not aligned evenly to each other.

Is this solvable?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}

.large, .small {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.large {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.small {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="large">Large</div>
  <div class="small">Small</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @Johannes [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50515262/1417223) it's a good idea to wrap both text divs in another container. But you don't need an `align-self: flex-end;` declaration for the `.inner-container`, just add `align-items: flex-end;` to the parent `div`. That way, you get one CSS rule less.

`display: inline;`, like `display: inline-block`, makes items align themselves by their baselines (based on the item with the biggest height, in this case the `.large` text) so you could change the `<div class="large">` and the `<div class="small">` to spans instead of divs. Since the default display property of `<span>` is inline, you can then skip the display declaration of `.large` and `.small`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.large, .small {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.large {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.small {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <span class="large">Large</span>
    <span class="small">Small</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to put both text DIVs into another wrapper (`.inner_container` in my snippet below) which gets the settings the texts previously had in order to align to the bottom, and apply `display: inline-block;` to the text DIVs: inline-blocks align to each other by their baseline by default, which is what you want if I understand correctly:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}

.inner_container {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.large,
.small {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.large {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.small {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner_container">
    <div class="large">Large</div>
    <div class="small">Small</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stellar solution!